# Parsing through a list of strings

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm writing a couple definitions in a web scraping program that I'm working on. The method I'm having trouble with right now, called parse_sentences(str_text) parses through the list of paragraph soup that I've scraped. Each element of the list contains some sentences and, using another method find_per(str), finds the index of the period. I append each sentence to a new list, new_text_str where each element is a single sentence. Then I remove that substring from the element of the text_str.

So for example, if I use a list like: `practice_str = ['This. That. Them', 'This. That. Them.', 'This. That. Them.']`

`practice_str[i]` indicates the first 'This. That. Them' element in `practice_str`. Then `find_per` finds the first period at index j = 4. That becomes the substring `[j = 0, j = 4]` I then append to a new list `new_text_str`.

In the end I want `new_text_str` to look like:

`new_text_str = ['This.','That.','Them.'....]` and so on for other i elements in the `text_str`.

I wrote the code below for it.

```
# Find the position of the period in the string
def find_period(str):
    per_index = str.index('.')
    return per_index

# Parse through the list of strings of sentences and add each sentence to a new list
def parse_sentences(text_str):
    new_text_str = []
    for i in range(len(text_str)):
        new_text_str.append([])

        for j in range(len(text_str[i])):
            while len(text_str[i]) != 0:
                per = find_period(text_str[i])
                new_text_str.append(text_str[i][0: per + 1])
                text_str[i] = text_str[i].replace(text_str[i][0: per + 1], ' ')

            i = i + 1

    print(new_text_str)

practice_str = ['This. That. Them.',
                'This. That. Them',
                'This. That. Them.',
                'This. That. Them.',
                'This. That. Them.']

parse_sentences(practice_str)

print(practice_str)
```

But when I run it, my traceback returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/richardlopez/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/wikiscraping.py", line 76, in 
parse_sentences(practice_str)
File "/Users/richardlopez/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/wikiscraping.py", line 19, in parse_sentences
per = find_period(text_str[i])
File "/Users/richardlopez/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/wikiscraping.py", line 8, in find_period
per_index = str.index('.')
ValueError: substring not found

I tried running through this by hand with a diagram and it checks out to me. Can anyone help me spot what's going over my head on this?

---

Answer (score 0):

Simple tracing shows the problem:

```
def find_period(str):
    print("ENTER find_period", str)
    per_index = str.index('.')
    return per_index
```

Output:

```
ENTER find_period This. That. Them.
ENTER find_period   That. Them.
ENTER find_period   Them.
ENTER find_period  
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

Look at your loop control:

```
        while len(text_str[i]) != 0:
```

You remove the words from the list, but you leave in some white space.  Once you remove all three words, you still have a string of one blank.  The loop continues, and your `index` call throws an exception.

You need to fix this: `strip` the result, or otherwise check for a string of nothing but white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use built in string methods such as .find() and .split() to make this easier.

.find() will return the starting index of the first occurrence of the substring that you give it as an argument.

For example:

```
practice_str = "This. That. Them."
practice_str.find('.')
```

Returns 4.

Additionally, you can use .split() to split a string into a list of strings on the character that you give as it's first argument.

For example:

```
practice_str = "This. That. Them."
practice_str.split('.')
```

Returns the list ["This", "That", "Them", ""].

One thing of note, if your last item ends in a period, then you will see that empty item there because of the way .split() divides up the string. I assume that you are giving an example and not the primary use case for your code, but in the event that I'm wrong, know you may want to remove those.

If you want to retain the period at the end of the words when you are done, you can always add it back in while you are looping over the content. It is not an elegant solution, but it would be easily done if you are already iterating over all the content.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Garcia, I tried split() and it seemed to do the trick, even though you say it's a little inelegant. It's funny because I had tried implementing a method using slicing as part of a list comprehension. But that seemed like killing a gnat with a sledgehammer and it was confusing to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method, for example

```
s = "This. That. Them."
s = s.split('.')
print(s)
```

As @user15073302 said, since the last element of `s` before the call to `split` ends with a point, at the end you will have a list with a zero lenght string
`['This', ' That', ' Them', '']`, you can remove it using the following

```
s = s.split('.')
last = len(s) - 1
if s[last] == '':
    s.pop(last)
print(s)
```

If you want to remove the spaces at the beggining of the strings you could use

```
def remove_spaces(slist: list):
    for i, s in enumerate(slist):
        if s[0] == ' ':
            slist[i] = s[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks @lldbee for the pop() suggestion to take out those empty elements. I was able to get each sentence in a row of my .csv. The minor trouble I'm still having is removing the unnecessary new lines from my soup because once they go into the csv they add blank rows. Which I don't want